# Scrolling a element without hardcoding values jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

For work, I have to have a element fixed upon scrolling (e.g scrolling down on a page will make the element adjust itself automatically to be viewable at all times). The issue I have to address is how to make this without hardcoding height values. Is there a way to do this?

Here is the code for it:

```
// fix the orange box to the top after scrolling a certain amount
$(window).scroll(function(e){
     var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

     // enforce a max based on current content length
     if ($(this).scrollTop() >= ($('.mainContent2ColLayout250').height() - 400))
         scrollTop = ($('.mainContent2ColLayout250').height() - 400);

     if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 340) 
         $('.fixedElement').css({'marginTop': scrollTop - 325, 'marginBottom': -1 * (scrollTop - 325)}); 

     if ($(this).scrollTop() < 340)
        $('.fixedElement').css({'marginTop': 0, 'marginBottom': 0}); 
});
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just set the element's `position` to `fixed`?

Comment: @user2101411 It is not clear how exactly you want to keep the element visible. `position: fixed` will cause the element to show up where it normally would in the document, but the fixed element will have no effect on the layout of the rest of the elements, and does not scroll with the page. There are other options, such as using `position: absolute` to set it to a specific location, such as the top-left corner or something, but I'm not sure what you actually want from your question description.

Comment: I'm being forced to use this code instead of doing the much simple and easier way of using position: fixed and have jquery add/remove classes or add styles..

Answer (score 1):

Apply

```
position: fixed
```

to that element

Comment: if I remove the javascript and add the position: fixed, it stops scrolling.

Comment: I'm trying to use this but it doesn't seem to be working either (I put .suggestionsBox-stock-stick to position: fixed; top: 0px;)

Comment: @user2101411 That should be working, I made a quick demo using position fixed here: https://jsfiddle.net/3bvnja6c/  
You must have some other CSS rules that are interfering, or something. Could you edit your post to include the HTML/CSS that you are working with?